# How to fix "Can not find the tag library descriptor" in eclipse 4.3 for my custom EL function

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jsp-tags, taglib

**setup:**

eclipse 4.3 with tomcat7 (running on localhost port 8080) configured as my test server.

**my EL class** (**folder structure:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjNuM.jpg) created using New => Java project in eclipse

```
package org.flinders.mycustomutilities;

//import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class MyCustomUtilities {
    public static String Hello(String name) {
        return "Heya " + name;
    }

 }
```

The class was then exported into a JAR file and imported into my maven repository. **It was then imported to my spring mvc project using this entry in pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flinders.mycustomutilities</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyCustomUtilities</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm not getting any errors in Eclipse's Maven POM editor.

**my TLD file** (stored in D:\work\eclipse\java.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT\WEB-INF which seems to be the working folder for tomcat)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>mytaglib</short-name>
    <uri>org.flinders.mycustomutilities</uri>

    <function>
        <name>Hello</name>
        <function-class>org.flinders.mycustomutilities.MyCustomUtilities</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.util.String Hello(java.util.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

not really sure what to put in the URI tag for my setup.

This is how I'm importing my custom EL function in my JSP file

```
<%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/mytaglib.tld" prefix="mine" %>
```

I've also tried

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/mytaglib.tld" prefix="mine" %>
```

but eclipse just can't see it. I have started tomcat via eclipse just in case that is required without any positive outcome. Still getting the error mentioned above.

Any ideas? I've been searching for examples on the net but they don't really give complete/working examples.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I was placing the tld file in the wrong place. I am importing the class/jar into my spring web mvc project. But I was putting the TLD file in the "ROOT" WEB-INF. I should've placed it in the WEB-INF for my web project. All working now thanks to all those who looked at it.